# Symfony form, dynamically change form on PRE_SUBMIT - error on validation

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have been trying for some time to modify an entity type form before its validation according to the data of another form.
The idea is that if someone changes the 'state' field, we propose the 'cities' of the 'state' in question.
So I use a PRE_SUBMIT event to modify the field but despite this, I always get an error at validation 'The selected choice is invalid'. Any idea what I'm missing?

My code :

```
$frm
->add(
                'villeNaissance',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'class' => Ville::class,
                    'label' => 'Ville de naissance',
                    'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                    'placeholder' => 'Séléctionnez un département',
                    'choices'=>[]
                    /*'query_builder' => static function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('v')
                            ->where('v.code like :dpt')
                            ->setParameter('dpt', '01___')
                            ->orderBy('v.libLong', 'ASC');
                    },*/
                ]
            )
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $evt) use ($villeRepo) {
                $dpt = $evt->getData()['departementNaissance'] ?? false;
                if ($dpt) {
                    $villesInDpt = $villeRepo->findByDpt($dpt);
                    //$evt->getForm()->remove('villeNaissance');
                    $evt->getForm()
                        ->add(
                            'villeNaissance',
                            EntityType::class,
                            [
                                'expanded' => false,
                                'multiple' => false,
                                'mapped' => false,
                                'class' => Ville::class,
                                'label' => 'Ville de naissance',
                                'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                                'required' => true,
                                'choices' => $villesInDpt,
                            ]
                        );

                }
            })
```

thx in advance

I tried to start from an empty 'choices' in the form, to delete or simply overwrite the form in question but the result is always the same.

so, i try the solution of @Marleen like that :
i remove the `PRE_SUBMIT` event on parent form and add that :

```
$builder->get('departementNaissance')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,function(FormEvent $evt) use ($villeRepo){
               $dpt = $evt->getForm()->getData();
               $parentForm = $evt->getForm()->getParent();

                $villesInDpt = $villeRepo->findByDpt($dpt->getCode());
                $parentForm->remove('villeNaissance');
                $parentForm
                    ->add(
                        'villeNaissance',
                        EntityType::class,
                        [
                            'expanded' => false,
                            'multiple' => false,
                            'mapped' => false,
                            'class' => Ville::class,
                            'label' => 'Ville de naissance',
                            'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                            'required' => true,
                            'choices' => $villesInDpt,
                        ]
                    );
                //dd($parentForm->get('villeNaissance')->getConfig()->getOption('choices'));
            });
```

I didn't manage to add my new cities to the existing city form (in the example, they just create a new form, they dont modify an existing one), so I tried to delete it and add it again or add it directly from the parent but nothing works for the moment.

PS :
the error dumped :

```
DeposerController.php on line 234:
Symfony\Component\Form\FormErrorIterator {#10235 ▼
  -form: Symfony\Component\Form\Form {#2956 ▶}
  -errors: array:1 [▼
    0 => Symfony\Component\Form\FormError {#10438 ▼
      #messageTemplate: "The selected choice is invalid."
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▼
        "{{ value }}" => "02007"
      ]
      #messagePluralization: null
      -message: "The selected choice is invalid."
      -cause: Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation {#10350 ▶}
      -origin: Symfony\Component\Form\Form {#4511}
    }
  ]
}
```

to be complete :
here is my FormType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Agorha\ConcoursType;
use App\Entity\Agorha\Departement;
use App\Entity\Agorha\Pays;
use App\Entity\Agorha\Sexe;
use App\Entity\Agorha\Ville;
use App\Entity\Candidature;
use App\Entity\ConcoursTypeEtape;
use App\Entity\EtapeDocumentUploade;
use App\Entity\Identite;
use App\Entity\UploadDocument;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Callback;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\GreaterThan;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\LessThan;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

class IdentiteType extends CompteCandidatType
{
    private $villeNaissance;
    private $prenom1;
    private $prenom2;
    private $identiteRepo;
    private $identiteId;
    private $identiteSess;
    private $session;
    private $user;

    public function __construct(private RequestStack $requestStack, private EntityManagerInterface $em, Security $security)
    {
        $this->session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
        $this->identiteRepo = $this->em->getRepository(Identite::class);
        $this->identiteSess = $this->session->get('app_deposer_identite');
        $this->user = $security->getUser();
        if (!is_null($this->identiteSess)) {
            $this->identiteId = $this->identiteSess;
        } else {
            $identite = $this->identiteRepo->findLastByUser($this->user);
            if ($identite) {
                $this->identiteId = $identite->getId();
            }
        }
        if ($this->identiteId) {
            $this->villeNaissance = $this->identiteRepo->find($this->identiteId)->getVilleNaissance();
            $identite = $this->identiteRepo->find($this->identiteId);
            $prenoms = $identite->getPrenoms();
            $this->prenom1 = $prenoms[0];
            $this->prenom2 = (array_key_exists(1, $prenoms) ? $prenoms[1] : false);
        }
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $sess = $request->getSession();
        if ($sess) {
            $candiRepo = $this->em->getRepository(Candidature::class);
            $candi = $candiRepo->find($sess->get('candidature'));
        }
        $etapeTypeRepo = $this->em->getRepository(ConcoursTypeEtape::class);
        $etapeType = $etapeTypeRepo->findOneByTypeAndRoute($this->session->get('typeConcours'), $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route'));

        //$etape = $etapeTypeRepo->findOneByRoute($request->get('_route'));

        $docToUpRepo = $this->em->getRepository(EtapeDocumentUploade::class);
        if ($etapeType && $candi) {
            $docToUp = $docToUpRepo->findByEtapeAndUploaded($etapeType, $candi);
        } else {
            $docToUp = null;
        }


        $typeRepo = $this->em->getRepository(ConcoursType::class);
        $villeRepo = $this->em->getRepository(Ville::class);
        $type = $typeRepo->find($request->getSession()->get('typeConcours'));
        $now = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $min = $now->modify("-" . $type->getContraintes()['ageMin'] . " years");
        $max = $now->modify("-" . $type->getContraintes()['ageMax'] . " years");

        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $evt) use ($villeRepo) {
                $dpt = false;
                $data = $evt->getData() ?? false;

                if ($data) {
                    $dpt = $data->getDepartementNaissance();

                    if ($prenoms = $data->getPrenoms()) {
                        if (count($prenoms) == 1) {
                            $evt->getForm()->remove('nonConcerne');
                            $evt->getForm()->add('nonConcerne', CheckboxType::class, [
                                'label' => 'Non concerné pas un deuxième prénom',
                                'mapped' => false,
                                'attr'=>['checked'=>'checked']
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($dpt) {
                    $villesInDpt = $villeRepo->findByDpt($dpt->getCode());
                    $evt->getForm()->remove('villeNaissance');
                    $evt->getForm()
                        ->add(
                            'villeNaissance',
                            EntityType::class,
                            [
                                'expanded' => false,
                                'multiple' => false,
                                'mapped' => false,
                                'placeholder' => $this->villeNaissance,
                                'class' => Ville::class,
                                'label' => 'Ville de naissance',
                                'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                                'choices' => $villesInDpt,
                                'required' => true,
                            ]
                        );
                }
            })
            /*->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $evt) use ($villeRepo) {

                $dpt = $evt->getData()->getDepartementNaissance() ?? false;
                if ($dpt) {
                    $villesInDpt = $villeRepo->findByDpt($dpt);
                    //$evt->getForm()->remove('villeNaissance');
                    $evt->getForm()
                        ->add(
                            'villeNaissance',
                            EntityType::class,
                            [
                                'expanded' => false,
                                'multiple' => false,
                                'mapped' => false,
                                'class' => Ville::class,
                                'label' => 'Ville de naissance',
                                'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                                'required' => true,
                                'choices' => $villesInDpt,
                            ]
                        );

                }
                dd($evt);

            })*/
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom de naissance',
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('nomUsage', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom d\'usage ou matrimonial',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('nonConcerne', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Non concerné pas un deuxième prénom',
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            ->add(
                'prenom1',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'data' => $this->prenom1,
                    'label' => 'Premier prénom',
                    'required' => true,
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank([], 'Le premier prénom ne peut être vide'),
                        new Regex('/\d/', 'Your prenom cannot contain a number', null, false)
                    ],
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'prenom2',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Deuxième prénom',
                    'data' => $this->prenom2,
                    'constraints' => [
                        new Callback(['callback' => static function (?string $data, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
                            $form = $context->getRoot();
                            if (!$data && !$form->get('nonConcerne')->getData()) {
                                $context->buildViolation('Merci d\'entrer votre deuxième prénom ou de cocher "Non concerné"')
                                    ->addViolation();
                            }
                        }])
                    ]
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'sexe',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'class' => Sexe::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Sexe',
                    'query_builder' => static function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                            ->orderBy('s.libLong', 'ASC');
                    },
                ]
            )
            ->add('villeEtrangerNaissance')
            ->add('codePostalEtrangerNaissance')
            ->add(
                'dateNaissance',
                BirthdayType::class,
                [
                    'attr'=>[
                        'max' => $min->format('Y-12-31'),
                        'min' => $max->format('Y-01-01'),
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Date de naissance',
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'required' => true,
                    'by_reference' => true,
                    'constraints' => [
                        new LessThan("-" . $type->getContraintes()['ageMin'] . " years", null, 'La date de naissance doit être inférieure à ' . $min->format('d/m/Y') . ' ou une dérogation d\'age est obligatoire'),
                        new GreaterThan("-" . $type->getContraintes()['ageMax'] . " years", null, 'La date de naissance doit être supérieure à ' . $max->format('d/m/Y') . ' ou une dérogation d\'age est obligatoire')
                    ]
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'paysNaissance',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'class' => Pays::class,
                    'label' => 'Pays de naissance',
                    'required' => true,
                    'query_builder' => static function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->orderBy("p.libLong", 'desc');
                    },
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'departementNaissance',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'required' => true,
                    'class' => Departement::class,
                    'choice_value' => function (?Departement $entity) {
                        return $entity ? $entity->getCode() : '';
                    },
                    'placeholder' => 'Séléctionnez un département',
                    'label' => 'Département de naissance',
                    /*'query_builder' => static function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                            ->orderBy('d.code', 'ASC');
                    },*/
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'villeNaissance',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'class' => Ville::class,
                    'label' => 'Ville de naissance',
                    'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                    'placeholder' => 'Séléctionnez un département',
                    'choices'=>[]
                    /*'query_builder' => static function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('v')
                            ->where('v.code like :dpt')
                            ->setParameter('dpt', '01___')
                            ->orderBy('v.libLong', 'ASC');
                    },*/
                ]
            );

            $builder->get('departementNaissance')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,function(FormEvent $evt) use ($villeRepo){
               $dpt = $evt->getForm()->getData();
               $parentForm = $evt->getForm()->getParent();

                $villesInDpt = $villeRepo->findByDpt($dpt->getCode());
                $parentForm->remove('villeNaissance');
                $parentForm
                    ->add(
                        'villeNaissance',
                        EntityType::class,
                        [
                            'expanded' => false,
                            'multiple' => false,
                            'mapped' => false,
                            'class' => Ville::class,
                            'label' => 'Ville de naissance',
                            'choice_label' => 'libLong',
                            'required' => true,
                            'choices' => $villesInDpt,
                        ]
                    );
                //dd($parentForm->get('villeNaissance')->getConfig()->getOption('choices'));
            });

        $uploadRepo = $this->em->getRepository(UploadDocument::class);
        $docUp = [];
        $docsBDD = $uploadRepo->findByUserAndIfGenerique($this->user);
        /*$docsBDD = $uploadRepo->findBy([
            'candidature' => $candi,
        ]);*/
        foreach ($docsBDD as $docBDD) {
            $docUp[] = 'files_' . $docBDD->getEtapeDocumentUploade()->getDocument()->getLibTechnique();
        }
        $this->doc($docToUp, $builder,$docUp);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Identite::class,
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
            'csrf_token_id' => 'task_item',
        ]);
    }
}
```

here is my controller :

```
#[Route('/deposer/reprise/{id}', name: 'app_deposer_reprise')]
    public function reprise(EntityManagerInterface $em, $id): Response
    {
        $candiRepo = $em->getRepository(Candidature::class);
        $candi = $candiRepo->findOneByIdentifiant($id);
        if ($candi) {
            if ($candi->isOwner($this->getUser())) {
                $crsRepo = $em->getRepository(Concours::class);
                $crs = $crsRepo->findOneByTypeAndOpen($candi->getConcoursType()->getId());

                if (!$crs) {
                    $this->request->getSession()->set('preInscription', true);
                }


                $this->request->getSession()->remove('lastRoute');
                $this->request->getSession()->set('typeConcours', $candi->getConcoursType()->getId());
                $this->request->getSession()->set('priseConnaissance', $candi->getPriseConnaissance());
                $this->request->getSession()->set('candidature', $candi->getId());

                $typeEtapeRepo = $em->getRepository(ConcoursTypeEtape::class);



                $candiEtapeRepo = $em->getRepository(CandidatureEtape::class);
                $candiEtape = $candiEtapeRepo->findLastByCandiByOrdre($candi->getId());

                /**
                 * cas du stop d une candidature dès la 1ere etape
                 * et donc pas d etape encore enregistrée en BDD
                 */
                if (!$candiEtape)
                {
                    $fstEtape = $typeEtapeRepo->findFirstByType($candi->getConcoursType()->getId());
                    if (!$fstEtape)
                    {
                        $this->request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Aucune étape encore configurée pour ce type de recrutement');
                        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_index');
                    }
                    return $this->redirectToRoute($fstEtape->getEtape()->getRoute());
                }
                $route = $candiEtape?->getEtape()->getEtape()->getRoute();

                $allEtapeBefore = $typeEtapeRepo->findEnfantByTypeOrdered($candi->getConcoursType(), $candiEtape->getEtape()->getEtape()->getParent(), $candiEtape->getEtape()->getOrdre());
                foreach ($allEtapeBefore as $etapeCandi) {
                    $route = $etapeCandi->getEtape()->getRoute();
                    if (array_key_exists($route, $this->routeEntity)) {
                        $repo = $em->getRepository($this->routeEntity[$route]);
                        $last = $repo->findLastByUser($this->getUser());
                        if ($last) {
                            $this->request->getSession()->set($route, $last->getId());
                        }
                    }
                }

                $sess = $this->request->getSession();
                $sess->set('lastRoute', 'app_deposer_reprise');
                return $this->redirectToRoute($route);
            }
            $this->request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'La candidature recherché ne semble pas vous appartenir');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_index');
        }
        $this->request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'La candidature recherché ne semble plus exister');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_index');
    }
```

Here is my twig

```
{{ form_start(formIdent, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent._token) }}
        {{ form_row(formIdent.nom,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.prenom1,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.dateNaissance,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.paysNaissance,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.departementNaissance,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.villeNaissance,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.sexe,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.nomUsage,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        {{ form_row(formIdent.prenom2,{'attr': {'class': 'fr-input'}}) }}

        <div class="fr-checkbox-group">
            {{ form_row(formIdent.nonConcerne) }}
        </div>


        <ul class="fr-btns-group--center fr-btns-group--inline">
            <li>
                <button class="fr-btn fr-btn--secondary" type="reset" value="remise à zéro">
                    Annuler
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="fr-btn" type="submit">
                    Suivant
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>

        {{ form_end(formIdent, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

and my JS :

```
domready(function() {
    const DPT = document.getElementById('identite_departementNaissance')
    DPT.addEventListener('change', e => {
        const selectedDPT = e.currentTarget.value
        const URL = '/api/villes?codePostal=' + selectedDPT + '&o[libLong]=asc'
        console.log('change dpt',selectedDPT)
        xhr.get(URL,true)
            .then(response => {
                if (response['hydra:totalItems']>0)
                {
                    let ville = document.getElementById('identite_villeNaissance')
                    let villes = response['hydra:member']

                    console.log('villes',villes)

                    ville.innerHTML = ''
                    villes.map(v=>{
                        let opt = document.createElement('option')
                        opt.value = v.code
                        opt.innerHTML = v.libLong
                        ville.appendChild(opt)
                    })
                }
            })
    })
})
```

Comment: The `PRE_SUBMIT` event on `cities` isn't called until after the `EntityType` has done some basic validation of its own, which is causing the error you're seeing. You need to use the `POST_SUBMIT` event on the `state` field, get its parent form and add the new `cities` selectbox to that. See the example here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i cannot modify a form during the ```POST_SUBMIT``` event.
i try your solution but unfortunately i have the same error. i put the new code in my original post

Comment: Did you also add the `PRE_SET_DATA` event listener from the example? That checks the existing `state` and adds the corresponding `cities` when the form is displayed to the user (on both add or edit). And the `POST_SUBMIT` then does the same thing, but only after the form has been submitted (since the user may have changed the `state`).

Comment: Yes, the ```PRE_SET_DATA``` event on parent form is still there and works properly : if the user had data in this entity, form is populate.
when i dump the form when he is submitted, the changes makes in the event are good, i see new form ```cities``` in place of the old one with the good choices values but the error is stille there despite that. i ll put the error in the post

Comment: Could you show your complete FormType, the Controller method and the template with the JavaScript (if any)?

Comment: I have added all the necessary files. thx

Comment: Does your `Ville` class have the standard `$id` + `getId()` method for the database identifier? Then it could be that you're sending a `Ville` `code` (the options rendered via JavaScript use the format `code => libLong`) while you are rendering/validating an `id` in the selectbox (the `EntityType` should then render as `id => libLong`).

Comment: omg....you re right....
I was so focused on my events that I forgot to check the most basic things...
there is indeed an inconsistency between the id and the code which are two different properties in my entity.
thank you very much!!!